# How do I install nginx's fancyindex module on CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, software-installation, nginx

I have nginx 1.10.2 installed on my CentOS 7 server. I'm trying to turn on fancyindex. I see that I need to install the fancyindex module somehow.

On Ubuntu, [according to this site](https://www.scalescale.com/tips/nginx/nginx-fancyindex-ubuntu/), there is a separate package called `nginx-extras` that adds fancyindex. I haven't been able to find the equivalent package in CentOS 7.

I have `nginx-all-modules.noarch` installed but that doesn't seem to include fancyindex.

I've been searching all over. Can someone point me in the right direction or definitively tell me that fancyindex doesn't have an `yum` way of installing on CentOS? I'd rather not compile from source but will if needed.

If there is no official way of installing, steps for compiling from source code would be appreciated.

```
[root@vps ~]# nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.10.2
built by gcc 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4) (GCC)
built with OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib64/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/proxy --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/fastcgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/uwsgi --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/scgi --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/run/lock/subsys/nginx --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-file-aio --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic --with-http_sub_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_degradation_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_perl_module=dynamic --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module --with-pcre --with-pcre-jit --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-google_perftools_module --with-debug --with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-z,relro -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -Wl,-E'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note: the repository in question has moved to a paid subscription model since this answer was posted.*

For CentOS 7 users with the official stable Nginx repository, fancyindex is included in the extra packages repository with dynamic modules. See https://www.getpagespeed.com/redhat.

```
yum -y install https://extras.getpagespeed.com/release-el7-latest.rpm
yum -y install nginx-module-fancyindex
```

Comment: Just 50 dollars to be able to use this repository

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any packages, so you'll need to compile from source.

Source:  https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/fancy_index/

Unpack the NGINX sources.

```
 $ gunzip -c nginx-?.?.?.tar.gz | tar -xvf -
```

Download the latest version using Git.

```
 $ git clone https://github.com/aperezdc/ngx-fancyindex.git ngx-fancyindex
```

Change to the directory which contains the NGINX sources, run the configuration script with the desired options and be sure to put an --add-module flag pointing to the directory which contains the source of the fancy indexing module.

```
$ cd nginx-?.?.?
$ ./configure --add-module=../ngx-fancyindex  [extra desired options]
```

Build and install the software.

```
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Configure NGINX by using the modules’ configuration directives.

Comment: Note for future visitors: `[extra desired options]` is important. Do a google search to find args for your platform.